# Calculate only selected row

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

I have a large workbook and am trying to increase performance.

Is it possible/viable to store my formulas in some sort of list contained within the code rather than in the cells on the spreadsheet?

```
Variable SelectedRow = the currently selected row
```

For example:

```
ColumnBFormula = A(SelectedRow) + 1
ColumnCFormula = A(SelectedRow) + 2
```

If the user enters 4 in cell A3, then the macro writes formulas above ONLY in empty cells B3 and C3, then converts to values. The rest of the spreadsheet remains unchanged (should only have values everywhere).

Then the user enters a 6 in cell A4 and the spreadsheet writes the formulas to empty cells B4 and C4, calculates then converts to values.

Thanks

Comment: Look at the `worksheet_change` event, and then the `.formula` of the cell, then just `cell.value=cell.value` does the changing of formula to value.  This is a site to assist with code, so no-one will write it for you, best to have a go first, you never know, you may fix it by reading a bit.  Also, the best way to learn imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Lastrow As Long

'Refer to Sheet1
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Check if Column A affected
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing And IsNumeric(Target) Then
        'Disable event to avoid event trigger
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target + 1
            Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Target + 2
        'Enable event
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End With
```

End Sub
**Instructions:**

[image]

**Enable Events**:

[image]

Comment: hi Error, i understand this is a private sub, but could you please explain how to run this? does it need to be called from a module? i've entered the code into "ThisWorkbook" but can't seem to run it.

Comment: @NthA please see the uploaded diagram on the answer. There is no need to run the code. the code will automatically run when there is any change in column A.

Comment: yes it worked, but i was testing and it has stopped and is no longer running on column A changes. i haven't changed any code. if i press run on sheet1 macro, it asks me to create a new macro. any ideas?

Comment: Enable events. See how on my answer.

Comment: thanks again. one last thing. so every time i enter a value which will cause an error (entering "abc" for example), i'm getting an error which is causing the code to stop and act as if application.events = false. to fix this, i have to reset the macro and press return in the immediate window. how can i IFERROR this to give an error and prompt for the correct data type?

Comment: I post another solution for this :-)

Comment: I see. Is there a more generic approach? I have written my question simply just so i can understand the logic. in reality, an isnumeric check is not sufficient to error check for the column.

Comment: I will be padding this template code out it will check multiple columns and perform different tasks determined by the column

Comment: Isnumeric will check if the import value is number will continue, if not the code will not be execute.

Answer (score 0):

Given you know what you want the code to do, you could do this without entering formulas.

In the VBA editor, add this code into the "ThisWorkbook" object ...

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim objCell As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each objCell In Target.Cells
        If objCell.Column = 1 Then
            If objCell.Value = "" Then
                objCell.Offset(0, 1) = ""
                objCell.Offset(0, 2) = ""
            Else
                objCell.Offset(0, 1) = objCell.Value + 1
                objCell.Offset(0, 2) = objCell.Value + 2
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Hopefully that works for you.

**FYI - You'll need to add the relevant error checking for values if not numeric etc, it will need to be improved.**